# Django + RabbitMQ + Celery . Not working from views

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django project

RabbitMQ is running (testing from command line, it receives messages)

Celery is running and recognising tasks.

Simplified tree of project:

```
├── wha/core
│   ├── wha/core/__init__.py
│   ├── wha/core/celery.py
│   ├── wha/core/settings.py
│   ├── wha/core/urls.py
│   └── wha/core/wsgi.py
├── wha/factura
│   ├── wha/factura/__init__.py
│   ├── wha/factura/admin.py
│   ├── wha/factura/forms.py
│   ├── wha/factura/models.py
│   ├── wha/factura/urls.py
│   └── wha/factura/views.py
└── wha/manage.py
```

## wha/core/**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

## wha/core/celery.py ([as docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html))

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')
from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('core')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

## wha/core/settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://XXX:XXX@localhost:5672//'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('factura.views')
```

## wha/factura/views.py

```
@task(name="factura.views.notify")
def notify(request, uid):

    factura = get_object_or_404(Factura, pk=uid)

    subject     = '%s - Your domain' % factura.contrato.dominio.nombre.upper()
    from_email  = 'Mail Name <asd@asd.com>'
    to          = [factura.contrato.dominio.cliente.email]
```

[...] blah blah, sends email, **uid** is really "factura" id. I think doesn't matter.

## Celery console output (debug)

```
 -------------- celery@nnbmp.local v3.1.19 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-15.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         core:0x10c451fd0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://hola:**@nnmbp:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . factura.views.notify
```

## URL for calling the view:

```
http://localhost:8000/factura/notify/8
```

Where 8 is the "factura" id,

## EDIT:

The thing that isn't working is that when I call "factura.notify" from the browser, Celery doesn't recognise the task being called, so it doesn't send a message to RabbitMQ.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @ookami.kb published unfinished by mistake. now it its. thanks

Comment: You still haven't said what is not working. What happens? Where is the part where you call Celery?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : When calling factura.notify, where the task decorator is, from the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that you are running views as celery tasks, that's plain wrong. Your views should offload some work (eg. generate a pdf, send an email) to Celery via a task (eg. `generate_invoice.delay()`, `send_email.delay()`), not be the task itself.

Right now Django resolves the url to the notify function (which is a callable) and simply executes it in sync and therefore it does not get published to your Celery message broker.

Here's an example of you should probably do:

```
def notify(request, uid):
    ...
    tasks.process_invoice.delay(invoice_id)
    return response


@task
def process_invoice(invoice_id):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks!, I put send_email_notification() in a file called tasks.py with the @task decorator. Now when I run "celery -A core worker --loglevel=DEBUG" I get the task registered like this: factura.tasks.send_email_notification. Then from the "notify(request, uid)" view I call: tasks.factura.tasks.send_email_notification() and I get 'TaskRegistry' object has no attribute 'factura' even when print tasks returns 
'factura.tasks.send_email_notification': <@task: factura.tasks.send_email_notification of core:0x10421f0d0>}. Do you know what could it be?

Comment: perhaps tasks.factura.tasks.send_email_notification -> factura.tasks.send_email_notification?

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be this line:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('factura.views')
```

That is a string, with parens around it. A single element tuple needs a comma:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('factura.views', )
```